# C error: called object 'coco_bbob_problem_allocator_t' is not a function or a function pointer

Tags: c, function, header-files, declaration

I need to implement a wrapper function around a set of functions with the same signature.
Basically, the idea is that the wrapper function should take as its first argument the wrapped function, which it should call by passing the rest of the wrapper's parameters.

I thus decided to create a function type in order to be able to pass it as an argument to another function (at least this is what I thought).

It's easier to write the code directly in order to visualize the situation.

So, I have the header file, names `coco.h`, that contains the following declaration, of a pointer to a function returning a pointer to the `coco_problem_t`type. (defined somewhere else in the codebase):

```
/**
  * @brief Allocates the coco problem noisy function
  * works as a wrapper around the function type coco_problem_allocate_f
 */
coco_noisy_problem_t *coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy(
  coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t *coco_problem_bbob_allocator,
  const size_t function, 
  const size_t dimension, 
  const size_t instance, 
  const long rseed, 
  const char *problem_id_template, 
  const char *problem_name_template
);
```

And wrote its definition in another file, named `suite_bbob_noisy_utilities.c` as follows:

```
coco_noisy_problem_t *coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy(
        coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t *coco_problem_bbob_allocator,
        const size_t function, 
        const size_t dimension, 
        const size_t instance, 
        const long rseed, 
        const char *problem_id_template, 
        const char *problem_name_template
    ){
    coco_problem_t *inner_problem = coco_problem_bbob_allocator(
      function, 
      dimension, 
      instance, 
      rseed, 
      problem_id_template, 
      problem_name_template
    );
    coco_noisy_problem_t *problem = coco_problem_allocate_f_wrap_noisy(inner_problem);
    return problem;
}
```

Now, the library needs to be build by running a python script with the shell command `python3 do.py run-c`. When I ran this comment, the build ended with the following error:

```
code-experiments/src/suite_bbob_noisy_utilities.c: In function ‘coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy’:
code-experiments/src/suite_bbob_noisy_utilities.c:197:37: error: called object ‘coco_problem_bbob_allocator’ is not a function or function pointer
code-experiments/src/suite_bbob_noisy_utilities.c:189:40: note: declared here
```

I don't understand why it is giving me this error, as I actually declared the variable `coco_problem_bbob_allocator` to be of the `coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t` function type.

Probably I'm missing some very important thing here, but Im fairly new to C (I had some not very extensive experience with C++ before being thrown in this project), so im sorry if this may be actually a trivial problem.

EDIT: I forgot to write here the declaration of the function type `coco_probolem_bbob_allocator_t`. It is declared in the `coco.h` header file as follows:

```
/**
 * @brief The allocate objective function type 
 * This is a template for functions that perform the allocation of the objective function 
 * given the number of dimensions of the problem
 */
typedef coco_problem_t *(*coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t)(
  const size_t function, 
  const size_t dimension, 
  const size_t instance, 
  const long rseed, 
  const char *problem_id_template, 
  const char *problem_name_template);
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the relevant type definitions. What is `coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t`?

Comment: Yeah sorry i just realised that i forgot to put it here, editing soon

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t` already is a pointer to a function.

When you define your parameter like this:

```c
coco_noisy_problem_t *coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy(
        coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t *coco_problem_bbob_allocator,
        const size_t function, 
        const size_t dimension, 
        const size_t instance, 
        const long rseed, 
        const char *problem_id_template, 
        const char *problem_name_template
    ){
    coco_problem_t *inner_problem = coco_problem_bbob_allocator(
      function, 
      dimension, 
      instance, 
      rseed, 
      problem_id_template, 
      problem_name_template
    );
```

Then you have a pointer to a function pointer.
To call it you need to use this:

```c
    coco_problem_t *inner_problem = (*coco_problem_bbob_allocator)(
      function, 
      dimension, 
      instance, 
      rseed, 
      problem_id_template, 
      problem_name_template
    );
```

But you do not need a pointer to a pointer:

```c
coco_noisy_problem_t *coco_problem_allocate_bbob_wrap_noisy(
        coco_problem_bbob_allocator_t coco_problem_bbob_allocator,
        const size_t function, 
        const size_t dimension, 
        const size_t instance, 
        const long rseed, 
        const char *problem_id_template, 
        const char *problem_name_template
    ){
    coco_problem_t *inner_problem = coco_problem_bbob_allocator(
      function, 
      dimension, 
      instance, 
      rseed, 
      problem_id_template, 
      problem_name_template
    );
```